# How to retrieve release and build data in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to build a custom dashboard using [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops). To display some charts about the releases and build pipelines. The question is how to retrieve information about the pipelines, is there a query language/utility that would provide such features?

Comment: What information do you want, Is the current state of the pipeline?

Comment: @1_1 Yes, the like the status of the pipeline, date if run, related project...etc. For example,  want to report on how many releases were done for the selected date and project

Comment: you can with rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_2